# SqlServer - How to display data of each month including months with no data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please help me in Sql server, I have table from where I'am getting date wise wise data.
Table structure .

```
Date     Amount
-----------------   
2019-05-04  16128.00
2019-05-06  527008.00
2019-05-07  407608.00
2019-05-10  407608.00
```

Above query I want to fill the missing date , My expectation as shown below

```
Date     Amount
-----------------   
2019-05-04  16128.00
2019-05-05  00
2019-05-06  527008.00
2019-05-07  407608.00
2019-05-08  0
2019-05-09  0
2019-05-10  407608.00
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Create a calendar help table (or cte) returning all wanted dates. outer join!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use calndar help table otherwise assign start date and from date like this `DECLARE @fromdate DATE = '20190504', @todate DATE = '20190510'` this from date and to date you can change.

```
    CREATE TABLE #amounttable
    (
      Dt DATE, 
      Amount BIGINT
    );
    INSERT into #amounttable(Dt, Amount) VALUES('2019-05-04',16128);
    INSERT into #amounttable(Dt, Amount) VALUES('2019-05-06',527008);
    INSERT into #amounttable(Dt, Amount) VALUES('2019-05-07',407608);
    INSERT into #amounttable(Dt, Amount) VALUES('2019-05-10',407608);


DECLARE @fromdate DATE = '20190504', @todate DATE = '20190510';

SELECT c.d as Date, Amount = COALESCE(s.Amount,0)
  FROM 
(
   SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @fromdate, @todate)+1)
 DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)-1, @fromdate)
 FROM [master].dbo.spt_values
 WHERE [type] = N'P' ORDER BY number
) AS c(d)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #amounttable AS s
  ON c.d = s.Dt
  WHERE c.d >= @fromdate
    AND c.d < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @todate);
```

for more reference [check the answer here from stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75486)

Answer (score 0):

One pretty simple method is to use a recursive CTE to generate the dates and then a `left join` to bring in the days:

```
with cte as (
      select min(t.dte) as dte, max(t.dte) as maxdate
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte), maxdate
      from cte 
      where dte < maxdate
     )
select cte.dte, coalesce(t.amount, 0) as amount
from cte left join
     t
     on cte.dte = t.dte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7b6fcb509e949288de9fbb08709a91d5) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that the default depth for recursion is 100, so for longer periods you should add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.